# How can I sort a list using the Levenshtein distance as criterion?

Tags: vb.net, sorting, levenshtein-distance

I'm trying to display several strings in a window. I've calculated the Levenshtein distance for all these strings before adding them to a list.

Now, I want to sort the list beginning with the string with the shortest distance. Is there a way without using a second list? I'm using VB.NET.

Thanks

Comment: It's not for us to write code for you or teach you from scratch. It's up to you to research as required and at least come up with an algorithm, and preferably attempt to implement that algorithm too. Only once you do that can encounter a specific issue that you can then ask a question about here.

Comment: If you created a class with properties named, say, MeasuredString As String and LevenshteinDistance As Integer, then you could create new instances of that class, add them to a list, and then sort them with [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a custom compare method to the lists sort-method.

The syntax is like below, where "YourComparer" is a function with your implementation for comparing two strings, and "list" is a list of strings.

```
list.Sort(Function(s1, s2) YourComparer(s1, s2))
```

"YourComparer" should return an integer value given two string, indicating if the first string should come before, after or have the same position as the second.

Below is an example implementation.

```
Private Function YourComparer(ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String) As Integer

    ' **** compare using your own implementation ****

    ' return less than zero if s1 should preceed s2
    ' return zero if s1 has same position in sort order
    ' return greater than zero if s1 should follow s2

    ' EXAMPLE using the length of strings to determine sort order
    ' Replace section with your own implementation
    If (s1.Length = s2.Length) Then Return 0 ' same position
    If (s1.Length > s2.Length) Then Return -1 ' should come before

    Return 1 ' should come after

End Function
```